# Teensy + IR camera + OpenCV

Tags: opencv, spi, teensy

I have never ever asked this kind of question on StackOverflow before, and I wonder if you could help me guys because it is a "bit" vague.

I have to design a project that uses Teensy (simple ARM platform) for getting data from IR camera (Flir, resolution 80x60) over SPI, and streaming these data to Linux/Windows running machine (through USB-serial) and doing something simple with OpenCV.

THE PROBLEM: The project lacks some "inovation". It should not be something very complicated, but rather different approach, or trying something new.

Do you have recommendations/tutorials/books/experience with working with above mentioned things? OR do you see a potential for teying something new?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: could you provide me with some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the [OpenCV Cookbook](http://www.laganiere.name/opencvcookbook/) for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project using this FLIR with a Teensy. It provides a thermal image using a small LCD screen (without any aditional computer).
https://hackaday.io/project/8994-diy-thermocam

So, the teensy can get data through spi.
Can the teensy send data through usb then ? Probably but you will have to check if the rate is high enough
.
Using OpenCV directly on teensy is not possible because of size of library. But you can probably make some basic image processing if the code is small enough.

The FLIR Lepton can be directly interfaced with Linux or Windows computer, so I don't really see the use of Teensy.

I would recommend a Raspberry Pi to interface the FLIR Lepton and then do some image processing. It's well documented on the web.